# Adding parameters to method in mousehoover

Tags: c#, mousehover, eventargs

I am having trouble making a mouse hoover method. The code is firstly a for-loop in which I create pictureboxes, and in the same for loop I would like to use the x and y worths in the loop.

This is the code where I create pictureboxes:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++){
    for (int y = 0; y < 9; y++){
        pb[x, y] = new PictureBox();
        pb[x, y].Location = new Point(x * 50 + 100, y * 50 + 100);
        pb[x, y].Width = 50;
        pb[x, y].Height = 50;
        pb[x, y].Visible = true;
        pb[x, y].BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        pb[x, y].BringToFront();
        this.Controls.Add(pb[x, y]);
        EventArgs e = new EventArgs();
        object sender;
        pb[x, y].MouseHover += new EventHandler(actionmousehoover(x, y, object sender));
    }    
}
```

The method called actionmousehoover is this one:

```
private void actionmousehoover(int x, int y,object sender, System.EventArgs e){
    resethoovercolors();
    //Om vertikal
    if(vertorhoriz = false){
        if(y+1 < 10 || y-1 < 1){
            pb[x, y].BackColor = Color.Red;
            pb[x, y + 1].BackColor = Color.Red;
            pb[x, y - 1].BackColor = Color.Red;

        }
    }
    if(vertorhoriz = true){
        if(x+1 < 10 || y-1 < 1){
            pb[x, y].BackColor = Color.Red;
            pb[x + 1, y].BackColor = Color.Red;
            pb[x - 1, y].BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }
}
```

The part with this:

```
pb[x, y].MouseHover += new EventHandler(actionmousehoover(x, y));
```

is working fine aswell as the actionmousehoover method do not have x and y as inparameter.

Comment: Is this Winforms?

Comment: Hoover or Hover?

Comment: You can not add more parameters than (object sender and EventArgs e) because they are predefined by C #

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this my creating your own picture box control that inherits from PictureBox and then add your own properties that you need.

```
public class MyPictureBox : PictureBox
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
}


MyPictureBox box = new MyPictureBox()
{
    Name = "pcBox1",
    X = 1,
     Y = 2
};

box.MouseHover += pictureBox1_MouseHover;
```

Then in the event handler, cast the sender to your control and access the properties.

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var x = ((MyPictureBox)sender).X;
     var y = ((MyPictureBox)sender).Y;
}
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

First, you can not add more parameters than (object sender and EventArgs e) because they are predefined by C #

Try this

```
pb[x, y].MouseHover += new EventHandler(this.PB_MouseHover);

private void PB_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    actionmousehoover(x, y)
}

private void actionmousehoover(int x, int y)
    {

        resethoovercolors();
        //Om vertikal
        if(vertorhoriz = false)
        {
            if(y+1 < 10 || y-1 < 1)
            {
                pb[x, y].BackColor = Color.Red;
                pb[x, y + 1].BackColor = Color.Red;
                pb[x, y - 1].BackColor = Color.Red;

            }
        }
        if(vertorhoriz = true)
        {
            if(x+1 < 10 || y-1 < 1)
            {
                pb[x, y].BackColor = Color.Red;
                pb[x + 1, y].BackColor = Color.Red;
                pb[x - 1, y].BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add parameters to the event handler; however, you can create your own derived `EventArgs` class containing these parameters.

```
public class PictureBoxEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public PictureBoxEventArgs(int x, int y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }

    public int X { get; }
    public int Y { get; }
}
```

For the picturebox to use this class, you must create you own extended picturebox class and override the `OnMouseHover` event trigger. (This is the real reason why the empty `EventArgs` are passed: to allow you to exetend them.)

```
public class PictureBoxEx : PictureBox
{
    protected override void OnMouseHover(EventArgs e)
    {
        var args = new PictureBoxEventArgs((Left - 100) / 50, (Top - 100) / 50);
        base.OnMouseHover(args);
    }
}
```

To get the array indexes, we perform the inverse calculation of the coordinates of `new Point(x * 50 + 100, y * 50 + 100)`.

Now, you can consume this event with

```
private void PictureBox_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (e is PictureBoxEventArgs args) {
        actionmousehoover(args.X, args.Y);
    }
}
```

Or subscribe to the event with a delegate

```
pb[x, y].MouseHover += (s, e) => {
    if (e is PictureBoxEventArgs args) {
        actionmousehoover(args.X, args.Y);
    }
};
```